# Why ngClick doen't work in directive isolate scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have simple directive with isolate scope:

```
app.directive('reportsLegend', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                label: '@'
            },
            template: '<div  style=" margin-top: 60px;">'+    
                      '   <div class="row" style="direction: rtl;">'+  
                      '       <legend>{{label}}</legend>'+                      
                      '   </div>'+
                      '<div class="row">'+ 
                      '<button class="btn" ><i  ng-click="getCSV()"></i>CSV</button>'+
                      '<button class="btn" ><i  ng-click="extendInNewTab()"></i>new window</button>'+
                      '<li><a href ng-click="getCSV()">zzzz</li>'+
                      '   </div>'+
                      '</div>',
                     link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) { 
                     console.log(elem);    

                scope.getCSV = function(){
                    alert('getCSV');
                };
                scope.extendInNewTab = function(){
                    alert('extendInNewTab');
                };
            }
        }
    }]);
```

However `ng-click` for two buttons doesn't fire but `href ng-click="getCSV()">` works.

How to make `ng-click` to work for buttons?

Do I need to use `$compile` or `$watch` or I missed something?

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/928/)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-click does not work with `<i>` because your `<i>` does not have anything inside, try moving it to `<button>`

```
'<button class="btn" ng-click="getCSV()"><i class="fa fa-download fa-1"></i>CSV</button>'+
'<button class="btn" ng-click="extendInNewTab()"><i class="fa fa-download fa-1" ></i>new window</button>'
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/930/)

or move the text to inside `<i>`:

```
'<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download fa-1" ng-click="getCSV()">CSV</i></button>'+
 '<button class="btn" ><i class="fa fa-download fa-1" ng-click="extendInNewTab()">new window</i></button>'
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/932/)

Comment: oh, my fault, didn't see that im in `<i>`. Tnx

Comment: @fessy: the main problem is your `<i>` is empty. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Bind `ng-click` with button, as `<i>` has no content. thus its not firing

```
'<button class="btn"  ng-click="getCSV()"><i class="fa fa-download fa-1"></i>CSV</button>'+
'<button class="btn"  ng-click="extendInNewTab()"><i class="fa fa-download fa-1"></i>new window</button>'+
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/929/)